# How to concat or merge two List<Dictionary<string, object>> in c#

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, merge, concatenation

I want merge or concat this list for one list.
How to concat this list without errors ?

Compiler Error Message: CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,object>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,object>>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

```
    List<Dictionary<string, object>> result1 = process1(); // OK
    List<Dictionary<string, object>> result2 = process2(); // OK
    List<Dictionary<string, object>> result3 = process3(); // OK
    List<Dictionary<string, object>> result4 = process4(); // OK
    List<Dictionary<string, object>> result5 = process5(); // OK
    
    var d1 = result1;

    if(result2 != null){
        d1 = d1.Concat(result2).ToList();
    }
    if(result3 != null){
        d1 = d1.Concat(result3);
    }
    if(result4 != null){
        d1 = d1.Concat(result4);
    }
    if(result5 != null){
        d1 = d1.Concat(result5);
    }
```

Comment: You need to use `.ToList()` after every `Concat()`

Comment: `Concat<T>` returns an `IEnumerable<T>` and `d1` is obviously a `List<T>`

Comment: This: https://dotnetfiddle.net/86R7WD

Comment: Or this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/hRfjOD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add ToList() not only to :

```
d1 = d1.Concat(result2).ToList();
```

but also to next concatenations:

```
if(result3 != null){
        d1 = d1.Concat(result3).ToList();
    } etc..
```

Comment: Thank u so much, I don't believe to me for this issue :(

Comment: List<Dictionary<string, object>> d1 = result1;

        if(result2 != null){
            d1 = d1.Concat(result2).ToList();
        }
        if(result3 != null){
            d1 = d1.Concat(result3).ToList();
        }
        if(result4 != null){
            d1 = d1.Concat(result4).ToList();
        }
        if(result5 != null){
            d1 = d1.Concat(result5).ToList();
        }
This is worked :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `d1` is a `List<>` but you have a `Dictionary<>`. You would need to add `ToList` to each line

But if you chain all the `Concat()` together, you only need `ToList()` at the end:

```cs
var empty = Enumerable.Empty<Dictionary<string, object>>()
var d1 = result1 ?? empty
    .Concat(result2 ?? empty)
    .Concat(result3 ?? empty)
    .Concat(result4 ?? empty)
    .Concat(result5 ?? empty)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Concat is a fine operator, but I think it is better if you use `d1.AddRange(result2);` etc.

The error you get is because the Concat returns an `IEnumerable<T>` while the AddRange operator returns a `List<T>`.

This way you prevent an unnecessary amount of casting with the `ToList()` operator.